# Django unit testing fails with postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unit-testing

I have the following problem. I have a bunch of unit tests that all passed when I was running sqlite3 and fail now that I'm using postgres. However, I only get fails if I run all the tests together. If I run them one by one all pass.

I have identified that the problem is due to the fact that the db isn't being flushed between tests. From the point of view of python's unit testing library, the correct way to do this, I think, is

```
class TestMyStuff(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ( set up stuff here )
    def teardown(self):
        ( database flush )
```

So my question is: what is the command in django to flush the database? I know how to do it with the manager, but how can I do it from inside python?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post some of your code? Django should be taking care of the teardown and initialization for you.  Do you need to run tests against postgres? If not you could run your tests in memory using sqlite3

Comment: @dm03514 You should *always* test against the database you intend to target in production, so yes, tests run against PostgreSQL are going to be important. Too many people rely on testing with SQLite, push to live on PostgreSQL, and *boom* something breaks. Like you, I'd like to see the test code as the user shouldn't have to be manually doing test cleanup.

Comment: If you use `django.test.TestCase`, and running the tests using `python manage.py test`, then Django should automatically take care of initializing a blank database before each test (unless there is something funky in your code that prevents this from happening, which of course there shouldn't be!). If you post the code someone can probably answer this fairly quickly.

Comment: Actually, I found that the premisse was wrong. The reasons for the fail wasn't what I thought it was. It was that I was assuming a way the private keys are automatically attributed, which was true on sqlite but not on postgres, but after I stoped making that assumption the re-written code works. How can I close down this question?

Comment: @oneloop What do you mean? Does Django not update the model.pk when saving to postgresql?